# Accessing a web service from an android phone

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

Hello I am new to Android .I have been given an Android project to do. As a part of my project I need to do the following :

1)Create an Android application that takes 3 inputs from user via EditText namely id,address and contact no, and has a submit button at the end to send that data

2)After clicking the submit button , a web service that we will create using Netbeans should get invoked and display it's contents on the phone to the user
The web service will basically contain some predefined data entries that I want to display it to the user with a checkbox
  say  eg.                xyz              
                          yax              
where 'xyz' and 'yax' are contents of my web service. The user selects any checkbox say 'xyz' , clicks another submit button below and the entire data namely id , address ,contact no , and now 'xyz' goes into a mysql database.

3) After reading [this](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Building-Java-Web-services-with-NetBeans-7) I am now aware of how to create a web service but the problem I have is how to invoke that web service from an android phone ???

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: I think your question should be: "How to invoke a webservice in android".. :)

Comment: @Farhan : Yes your right , i should have asked the question in that way, people might just get confused seeing my questn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use `web-service` from URL.

Comment: Hey u mean suppose my url is say http://localhost:8080/Mywebservice/demo.wsdl? then when i open the application in my phone automatically a browser will open with that url ..is that what u mean to say ?

Comment: ya you can do that from particular URL but first you need to host. then you make a web-service and generate xml base file . and at the end you need to parse (by SAX parser or DOM parser).

Comment: sorry I didn't get u completely . Just tell me whether this is rite or wrong --> Basically Wen we create a web service in netbeans using SOAP or anything and wen we run that service our browser gets launched with dat service URL and we see contents of web service , say if i write a statement to print hello world , then it will be displayed on my browser. But now instead of that what I want is that my Mysql database values should get displayed on browser and also android phone when i paste dat url in my phone browser. This is what I am planning to do.. I didn't get the hosting part of ur answer

Comment: you need a php developer , by help of him you generate xml formatted file. so first you tell me do you display any webpage to your phone or get some data? because xml give facility to data in response.

Comment: Yup i need to display a web page on the phone that will contain my database records of mysql along with checkboxes in a kind of ListView. User then checks records he wants, taps the submit button and the records he checkd go into the database under the corresponding columns

Comment: so there are tow way to do this 
1. make a web page which is mobile compartible version for e.g: m.google
2. implement webservices concept and make xml. and implement your idea.i a mobile there are mostly use webservice concept becase it is more faster then other

Comment: yup accepted it ..Basically my problem is exposing database via a web service and not accessing a web service..I am sorry for framing the question in a wrong way ..After reading this[link](http://netbeans.org/kb/69/websvc/rest-mysql.html) I got to know that it can be done but my only problem now is to show that database as a ListView when i access it frm phone ..anyone with the solution for this ?

Comment: ya,if your xml is ready and host it then you can do it by using any prser
1. sax parser
2  dom parser.

SAX parser is better then dom so i send to u a linkby which you can learn the SAX parser.
http://www.google.co.in/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sax+parser+tutorial+in+android

Comment: hey thanks ..I will start implementing it today ..if any problems I will post it over here :-)

Comment: Hey this link [http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser] helped me to parse my xml file .If u see the output given there it is just a simple ListView , Now I want to add checkbox such that user can check the name=AndroidPeople and website and WebSiteCategory and then click submit button to send the checked data to some other database via a web service..How to do that ?